# Macro to Copy and duplicate an existing sheet and rename it through a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a monthly expense workbook with set template for every months expense calculation. I want to build a macro with which, on click of a button my template worksheet is duplicated and is renamed automatically month wise.

For example, my template worksheet is named as "Projections - Temp 23", on click of a button, a new worksheet should be generated (ex:- "Projections - Temp 23 (1)"), and automatically rename it as the current month i.e. "Sep 2023".

I was able to configure the button and generate the duplicate template but am not able to rename it.

This is the code am using to generate the duplicate:

```
Sub copysheet()
   
' copysheet Macro

Sheets("Projections - Temp 23").Select
Sheets("Projections - Temp 23").Copy After:=Sheets(30)    
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Change activesheet name with `ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "MMM YY")`

Answer (score 2):

### Copy and Rename a Template Worksheet

[image]
[image]

```vb
Sub AddProjectionsSheet()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Add Projections Sheet"
    
    Const TEMPLATE_NAME As String = "Projections - Temp 23"
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "mmm yyyy"
    Const ENFORCE_DEFAULT_FORMAT As Boolean = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Store the new name in a variable.
    
    Dim dName As String
    
    If ENFORCE_DEFAULT_FORMAT Then
        dName = Application.Text(Date, DATE_FORMAT) ' e.g. 'Sep 2023'
    Else
        dName = Format(Date, DATE_FORMAT) ' locale-dependent
    End If
    
    ' Check if the sheet exists.
    
    Dim dsh As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(dName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This month's projections sheet (""" & dName _
            & """) already exists!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Add a copy of the template and rename the copy.
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(TEMPLATE_NAME)
    tws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' after the last workbook's sheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    dws.Name = dName
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Added this month's projections sheet (""" & dName & """).", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone I just modified the code as follows, and it worked:

```
Sub copysheet()

    Sheets("Projections - Temp 23").Select
    Sheets("Projections - Temp 23").Copy After:=Sheets(30)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "MMM-YY")
       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the modified code below (I've added explanations inside the code's comments):

```
Option Explicit


Sub copysheet()

' copysheet Macro

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim CurrMonthYearStr As String

' get the Month and Year of current Date
CurrMonthYearStr = Format(Date, "mmm yyyy")

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projections - Temp 23")

Sht.Copy After:=Sht ' copy worksheet and place after current sheet
Set NewSht = ActiveSheet

NewSht.Name = CurrMonthYearStr ' new worksheet's name
    
End Sub
```